# Redirection 301

Tags: redirection

I used the redirect module to do a 301 redirection. Everything works fine for the first few hours. Then, afterwards when I enter the old link, the redirection doesn't work anymore. If I go and clear caches and try again , the redirection works again. Then If I wait again, the redirection stops to work.. so each time I have to clear cache and that's annoying ! Why is that happening?

Comment: Welcome to Drupal Answers!  That's really difficult to tell from afar. To find this out we need to know all steps to reproduce your setup and config. Most likely server-side caching.

Comment: did you try using the .htaccess file to manage redirections ?